# Obj-C: UITableView update datasource cross-class

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, singleton, uitableview

Ok, so how it currently stands; I have a UIViewController (with a custom class for tidiness) called PlaylistController. This controller implements the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource protocols and rather crudely populates the UITableView with some basic information from an NSMutableArray:

PlaylistController.h:

```
@interface PlaylistController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    @public NSMutableArray* _playlists;
    @public NSMutableArray* _tracks;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
```

PlaylistController.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    tableView.delegate = self;
    tableView.dataSource = self;
    _playlists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Heyy", @"You ok?", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)aTableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [_playlists count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    // Dequeue or create a cell of the appropriate type.
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [_playlists objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Which works fine, when I click the appropriate tab to show the UIViewController, it's all populated. My issue comes with changing the datasource when new data becomes available.

How would I go about updating the datasource, considering that the new data comes from a different class? Singleton?

Comment: What's the issue? You set new values in `_playlists` and `_tracks`, and call `[tableView reloadData];` to let everything handle itself automatically, no?

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't clear! It's more **how** do I update `_playlists` **from another class** and then call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: What "other class" do you have in mind? If `PlaylistController` is on the screen, there's no other class that could have control; if it is not on the screen, the `viewWillAppear` can take care of the update.

Answer (score 0):

Expose your "playlists" array as a public property on your view controller.  Implement a custom setter that prompts the tableview to reloadData when set:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray* playlists;

...

@synthesize playlists=_playlists;

...

- (void) setPlaylists: (NSArray*) playlists
{
    _playlists = playlists;

    if ( self.isViewLoaded )
    {
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```